# Where to put a private git repository for Weblate and how to reference it via ssh?

Tags: git, ssh, weblate

I have a private git repository inside user directory: `/dir/subdir/.git`

In "Add Component" form field "Source code repository:" I specify:

```
ssh://user@domain/dir/subdir
```

The error I get is:

> Failed to fetch repository: fatal: '/dir/subdir' does not appear to be a git repository fatal: Could not read from remote repository. Please make sure you have the correct access rights and the repository exists. error: Could not fetch origin (1)

Answer (score 1):

I am using `ssh` to access my repositories over ssh with something like this without any problems:

```
user@domain:dir/subdir
```

Note, that `ssh` protocol is implicit and you need to use `:` instead of `/` between `domain` and `dir`.